# Assertion Failure

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, assertion

I am developing an iPad application with SDK4.2. I have a very strange error when touching any textField in my application. The first time I touch, the keyboard is shown, but when a second touch is done in the object I obtain following trace.
And it occurs also in any TextField shown in a HTML page with a UIWebView object.
Any ideas?
I am really confused with this..    Thanks in advance!

```
2010-12-17 11:53:11.697 BancoPopular[48914:207] *** Assertion failure in -[UIButtonLabel setTextColor:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UILabel.m:314
2010-12-17 11:53:11.699 BancoPopular[48914:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: color'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01730be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018855c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x016e9628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x0013947b -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x0045d1dc -[UILabel setTextColor:] + 164
    5   UIKit                               0x0052177b -[UIButton layoutSubviews] + 1337
    6   UIKit                               0x005f3420 -[UICalloutBarButton layoutSubviews] + 54
    7   QuartzCore                          0x011a4451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    8   QuartzCore                          0x011a417c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    9   QuartzCore                          0x011a4088 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 111
    10  UIKit                               0x0051f2ff -[UIButton titleLabel] + 81
    11  UIKit                               0x005f81d1 -[UICalloutBarButton setContentScale:] + 141
    12  UIKit                               0x005f6c5d -[UICalloutBar _updateVisibleItems] + 2240
    13  UIKit                               0x005f2970 -[UICalloutBar appear] + 211
    14  UIKit                               0x005eaaa9 -[UITextSelectionView showCommandsWithReplacements:] + 291
    15  Foundation                          0x000bd7f6 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01711fe3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01713594 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0166fcc9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0166f240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0166f161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x01e25268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x01e2532d GSEventRun + 115
    23  UIKit                               0x0034d42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    24  BancoPopular                        0x0000292e main + 84
    25  BancoPopular                        0x000028d1 start + 53
    26  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully what exception was about. It said "reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: color'", somewhere in your code, you provide wrong parameter that is supposed to be valid colors. Apparently, it seems like you use UIButton with label and set its color but not valid.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have some object going away somewhere, and that object contains the "color" value.

Most likely you received an autoreleased value from some call and did not retain it, so it went "poof" when the UI came up for air.